Is it possible to add an inactivity timer to a shared Excel workbook?
I have a shared excel workbook, I'd like to add an inactivity timer. If a user is inactive in the workbook for 2 hours or more, I want excel to display a prompt to the user. I want the prompt to ask the user if they are still there. If they answer yes, close the dialog box and keep excel open. If they do not answer within 10 minutes, save and close excel.
Here is the code I have been trying but I'm having issues with the script. I am able to display a prompt for the user, but it's not closing the workbook when that prompt isn't interacted with after the set time.  For testing purposes, I am using 2 minutes inactivity, then 30 seconds to respond to the prompt before excel is saved and closed.
Here is my module I added:
Dim InactivityCheckInterval As Double
Dim InactivityDuration As Double
Dim LastActivityTime As Date
Dim PromptTimeout As Double
Dim PromptStartTime As Date
Dim IsPromptActive As Boolean

Sub StartInactivityTimer()
    ' Set the intervals
    InactivityCheckInterval = TimeValue("00:01:00") ' Check every 1 minute
    InactivityDuration = TimeValue("00:02:00") ' 2 minutes of inactivity
    PromptTimeout = TimeValue("00:00:30") ' 30 seconds to respond to the prompt
    
    ' Initialize variables
    LastActivityTime = Now
    IsPromptActive = False
    
    ' Start the inactivity check
    ScheduleInactivityCheck
End Sub

Sub ScheduleInactivityCheck()
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Now + InactivityCheckInterval, Procedure:="CheckInactivity", Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub CheckInactivity()
    If Not IsPromptActive And (Now - LastActivityTime) >= InactivityDuration Then
        IsPromptActive = True
        PromptStartTime = Now
        Dim UserResponse As VbMsgBoxResult
        UserResponse = MsgBox("Are you still there?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1 + vbSystemModal, "Inactivity Check")
        If UserResponse = vbYes Then
            LastActivityTime = Now
            IsPromptActive = False
            ScheduleInactivityCheck
        Else
            ' Schedule the close event to happen in 30 seconds
            Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Now + PromptTimeout, Procedure:="CloseExcel", Schedule:=True
        End If
    Else
        ScheduleInactivityCheck
    End If
End Sub

Sub CloseExcel()
    ' Ensure that we only close Excel if the prompt is still active and the timeout has elapsed
    If IsPromptActive And (Now - PromptStartTime) >= PromptTimeout Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.Quit
    End If
End Sub

Sub ResetActivityTimer()
    LastActivityTime = Now
    If IsPromptActive Then
        IsPromptActive = False
    End If
    ScheduleInactivityCheck
End Sub


Here is the workbook module:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    StartInactivityTimer
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    ResetActivityTimer
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    ResetActivityTimer
End Sub


I've got users that forget to close the workbook at the end of the day and it's raised a few issues.  Is what I'm trying to do possible?  TIA!
Editing my post to update what I have done so far.
I decided to forgo prompting the user for input and am placing the timer in a shape that has the StartCountdown macro assigned to it.  Here is my code:
WORKBOOK MODULE CODE:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call start_Countdown
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Name = "Data" Then
        ' Check if the change is within the "Data_Entry" table
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim tbl As ListObject
        Set tbl = Sh.ListObjects("Data_Entry")
        If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
            If Not Intersect(Target, tbl.Range) Is Nothing Then
                Call start_Countdown
            End If
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub


STANDARD MODULE:
Option Explicit

Public Close_Time As Date
Public Timer_Interval As Date
Public Timer_Enabled As Boolean

Sub start_Countdown()
    ' Stop any existing countdown
    stop_Countdown
    
    ' Set the countdown time
    Close_Time = Now() + TimeValue("02:00:00")
    Debug.Print "Close_Time set to: " & Close_Time
    Application.OnTime Close_Time, "close_wb"
    
    ' Set the timer interval for updating the countdown
    Timer_Interval = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Timer_Enabled = True
    Debug.Print "Timer_Interval set to: " & Timer_Interval
    Application.OnTime Timer_Interval, "UpdateCountdown", , True
    
    ' Initialize the shape with the countdown message
    UpdateCountdownShape "Workbook will close in 02:00:00"
End Sub

Sub stop_Countdown()
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Cancel any scheduled close event
    If Close_Time <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Canceling Close_Time: " & Close_Time
        Application.OnTime Close_Time, "close_wb", , False
    End If
    ' Cancel any scheduled update event
    If Timer_Interval <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Canceling Timer_Interval: " & Timer_Interval
        Application.OnTime Timer_Interval, "UpdateCountdown", , False
    End If
    Timer_Enabled = False
    UpdateCountdownShape "Countdown stopped"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub close_wb()
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Stop the timer
    stop_Countdown
    ' Close the workbook
    Debug.Print "Closing workbook at: " & Now
    ThisWorkbook.Close True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub UpdateCountdown()
    On Error Resume Next
    If Timer_Enabled Then
        Dim TimeLeft As Date
        TimeLeft = Close_Time - Now
        Dim TimeLeftStr As String
        TimeLeftStr = Format(TimeLeft, "hh:nn:ss")
        UpdateCountdownShape "Workbook will close in " & TimeLeftStr
        If TimeLeft <= 0 Then
            ' Timer has run out, close the workbook
            close_wb
        Else
            Timer_Interval = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
            Debug.Print "Updating Timer_Interval to: " & Timer_Interval
            Application.OnTime Timer_Interval, "UpdateCountdown", , True
        End If
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub UpdateCountdownShape(msg As String)
    Dim shp As Shape
    On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Shapes("CountdownShape")
    If Not shp Is Nothing Then
        shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.text = msg
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub


The workbook is monitoring my "Data_Entry" Table for changes.  If no changes are made in that table in 2 hours, the workbook will close. The timer resets when a change is made to the table.
The problem I'm having is that the workbook keeps closing prematurely.  I have the timer set to 2 hours and it's closing within 5 minutes sometimes.

Your code will stop when it shows the messagebox, until someone interacts with it.  Consider maybe unhiding a worksheet which has the prompt and a couple of buttons, so your code doesn’t hang waiting for the user.

… or create a user form to replace the Msgbox

I just edited my post to show what changes I have made.  I have it almost working without the user prompt. The issue I'm having now is that the workbook keeps closing prematurely.

In stop_Countdown you don't reset Close_Time to zero
